# IBM Reflection programming- MoveCursor function issue

Tags: vba, host, cursor-position, attachmate-reflection

In IBM Reflection host, i am trying to run a VBA macro for traversing through different screens and fill required information (in a predefined template kind of a screen) to create orders in the system.

In the process, i am trying to utilise the functions- "Session.MoveCursor" and "Session.CursorRow", "Session.CursorColumn" for moving the cursor to a desired position and then reading the cursor position information (to verify the position before writing data on HOST screen)

**Code:**

```
Dim currRowPos as Integer
Dim currColPos as Integer
Session.MoveCursor targetRowPos, targetColPos ' move cursor position
DoEvents ' custom logic to wait or inlcude delay 1 sec or more, mentioned only single code statement here 
currRowPos = Session.CursorRow 'get cursor current row position
currColPos = Session.CursorColumn 'get cursor current column position
'check current cursor position and write data onto HOST screen
If targetRowPos = currRowPos And targetColPos = currColPos Then
    Session.TransmitANSI "xyz" 'write xyz on HOST screen
End If
```

I am trying to write some information on to Host at the desired cursor position and traverse to next screen. In the due process, i am going going back and forth to fill information for multiple items (one at a time).

Sometimes I am facing an issue where the above logic (code) is executed and the cursor is still in old position (not in the desired new row, column position) and the program started writing data in the old position rather than the desired/ target position resulting in a programming error (i.e. 'Session.CursorRow' and 'Session.CursorColumn' are outputting new desired cursor position, when in real time the cursor in its old position on HOST screen).

If anyone has encountered this issue before and/ or have any solution in mind, can you please share the same . Thank you.

> **Pasted Code from comments below**

**here is the delay function being used in the vba program- code**

```
Public Sub DelayScript(Seconds As Integer) 
   Dim PauseTime, START 
   PauseTime = Seconds 
   START = Timer ' Set start time. 
   Do While Timer < START + PauseTime 
      DoEvents ' Yield to other processes. 
   Loop 
End Sub
```

*IBM HOST Programming Reference: http://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/14.x/prog-ref/ibm/*

Comment: Is the "custom logic to wait or inlcude delay 1 sec or more" doing any more processing?  Also, what backend are you connecting to?  If it's something like Easytrieve, it's usually easier to insert Tabs to advance through fields.

Comment: The delay is to catch up to the HOST (which is slow sometimes during peak load times), nothing more.

Also in the macro i am trying to read from an excel file and the HOST is connecting to the mainframe system.
Not sure why the 'Session.CursorRow' and 'Session.CursorColumn' are still returning the new position values when host is still not ready in the new positions

Comment: Can you post the delay code?

Comment: here is the delay function being used in the vba program-
`code`
Public Sub DelayScript(Seconds As Integer)
    Dim PauseTime, START
    PauseTime = Seconds
    START = Timer   ' Set start time.
    Do While Timer < START + PauseTime
        DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
End Sub
`code`

Comment: Thought it was something like that. See below  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, latency in the underlying connection is interfering with your code's timing.  In general, instead of `DoEvents` or timing code, you should be using the `Wait*` methods and let Reflection take care of the timings *for you*.  My guess is that you need something more like this:

```
With Session
    .MoveCursor targetRowPos, targetColPos 
    '10 second timeout.
    .WaitForEvent rcEnterPos, "10", "", targetRowPos, targetColPos 
    'Verify that you didn't time out.
    If targetRowPos = .CursorRow And targetColPos = .CursorColumn Then
        Session.TransmitANSI "xyz" 'write xyz on HOST screen
    End If
End With
```

Alternately (assuming it's a field) you wait on `rcEnterField` instead of `rcEnterPos`.  See the [documentation here](http://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/14.x/prog-ref/ibm/hlpid_m_waitforevent.htm).

Comment: I think this might be the solution i am looking for, being a newbie to the IBM Reflection and going through all the documentation, i think i missed the wait functions.

Thank you for the suggestion @Comintern, will try and keep you posted

Comment: Thank you @Comintern, that worked great. I am gonna have to run this during peak load times and see how the result would be. Thanks again for the quick response. Thumbs up :)

Comment: I have completed multiple load tests and results look good. I was stumbling on this scenario for the last 2 days and finally you helped me fix it, that's awesome :)